# vue nested event fired but parent one is omited

Tags: vue.js

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/KazanExpress/vue-simple-suggest#ref-event-handlers) for autocomplete select, and in my logic, I also want to trigger `require` validation (from vuelidate library) on the fly. I want to trigger the `require` validation rule when the user focuses out the input and when the user selects some value from the suggestion list.

And for some reason when I'm selecting a value by the first time  from the suggestion list it's triggering `focusout` event not a `select`, probably b-z list is out of input focus, but when I'm selecting an item from the list by the second time it's triggering `select` event not `focusout` (as it should). NOTE: vue trigger `select` event only when I select value for the second time, first, third and all next times it's always triggering `focusout` event.

Question: why it's not triggering `select` event and how to force triggering it??

Code snippet:

```html
<vue-simple-suggest v-model="city.searchInput" 
                    :debounce="300" 
                    :min-length="2" 
                    display-attribute="name" 
                    value-attribute="id" 
                    :list="getCity" 
                    :filter-by-query="true" 
                    @select="citySelect">
    <input type="search" 
           class="form-control" 
           placeholder="Place of birth" 
           @focusout="cityError" />
</vue-simple-suggest>
```

```js
methods: {
    cityError() {
        console.log('cityError');, // <== when I select some item from suggestions list by the first time this event triggered
    },
    citySelect() {
        console.log('citySelect'); // <== when I'm clicking by input second time (the suggestions list already loaded) and select some (or same) value from suggestions list this event triggered
    },
    getCity() {
        // here should be ajax call, but for now just dummy data
        return [{
                "id": "691b237b0322f28988f3ce03e321ff72a12167fd",
                "name": "Paris",
                "lat": -33.8599358,
                "lng": 151.2090295
            },
            {
                "id": "691b237b0322f28988f3ce03e321ff72a12167fs",
                "name": "New York",
                "lat": -33.8599358,
                "lng": 151.2090295
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I open an issue on github https://github.com/KazanExpress/vue-simple-suggest/issues/353 (it has detailed information and small video which showing the issue, you can check browser console), but I'm not sure it's related to the library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw in the [documentation](https://github.com/KazanExpress/vue-simple-suggest#emitted-events) of the library that it allows blur event. Could you try `@blur` in `vue-simple-suggest` component instead of `@focusout` in the input?

Otherwise you can run a controller in the `@select="checkCitySelection"` to avoid the `@focusout` event in the input:

```
checkCitySelection(citySelected) {
  this.$v.city.value.$touch();
  if (this.$v.city.value.$invalid) this.cityError()
  else this.citySelect();
}
```

Comment: well as you can see I have ` :min-length="2" ` so it will not show the suggestions dropdown until the user types 2 or more characters. But I want to show the error message when the user click on input and after that select some other element without typing, in that case, a dropdown will not visible yet neither `select` event. Goin to try blur event

Comment: yeah, blur working, thanks! Btw maybe you know why it does not fire select event in case of focusout? Actually, why it fires it only on the second time I select it?

Comment: I think you can add also the `@focus` event that the lib provides, for this: `But I want to show the error message when the user click on input`.

Comment: I don't know why, maybe if you go deep into the lib they are using `@focusout`/ `@blur` input event to provide you their own `@blur` event, and it raises some conflicts. I just think the lib is not meant for handling your own input events, as I read, they provide you some inputs events. Maybe adding some `.prevent` to stop propagation and just fire the one you defined. Not sure anyway!